# Is $-f(x(t), t) = f(-x(t), t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be locally Lipschitz continuous in the first argument and continuous in the second argument, and consider
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t), t),\quad x(0) \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}

Can we say
\begin{equation}
-\dot{x}(t) = -f(x(t), t) = f(-x(t), t)? 
\end{equation}

My intuition says no, but I'm not sure if the properties of $f$ given above would help in proving this. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Context? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no : the constant function $f(x,t)= 1$ is locally Lipschitz in the first variable and continuous in the second, but the solution $x(t)$ of :
$$\dot x = f(x,t)$$
does not satisfy your equation.